# Create a dictionary of all distinct words from a list of string C#

Tags: c#, string

I was looking at a tutorial about data mining algorithms and couldn't quite copy a line of code from the tutorial to generate my own "vocabulary" variable (as the tutorial called it).

Basically the code on the tutorial page is:

```
List<string> x = textBox1.Text.Split(',').ToList();
var vocabulary = x.SelectMany(GetWords).Distinct().OrderBy(word => word).ToList();
```

But when I copy it into visual studio, I get the following error:

> The name 'GetWords' does not exist in the current context.

Trust me, I am not missing anything from the tutorial. What I am looking for is a method to achieve the following:

[image]

Taking this and generating something like this:

[image]

(Ignore the numbers on the tutorial image)

I've tried the following codes but they return entire elements from the string:

```
        //var vocabulary = x.OrderBy(q => q).Distinct().ToList();

        //var vocabulary = (from w in x
        //                  select w).Distinct().ToList();

        //         IEnumerable<Word> vocabulary =
        //(from w in x.Distinct()
        // select new Word { Text = w.ToString() }).ToList();
```

[Link to the tutorial](https://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/10/svm-tutorial-classify-text-csharp/)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: GetWords is a functor(method which gets a parameter of your collection item type).

Comment: it looks like there is no variable or method named `GetWords` available in scope

Comment: Exactly, there isn't, I just want to achieve the same results as the tutorial

Comment: Yep googled it tonnes of times

Comment: `I was looking at a tutorial about data mining algorithms` Which tutorial?

Comment: You don't have a `GetWords` method. This isn't a standard method, you need to write this yourself.

Comment: I am genuinely sorry, I wish I had scrolled down the code first. Honest apologies

Comment: So a link to the tutorial in question would help. You are missing a method. It's possible that the tutorial didn't intend to give you that function and it's just a place holder. Presumably `GetWords` just takes a string and splits it on word boundaries, which is trivial to do.

Comment: How about using a HashSet? The item won't get added if it already exists.

Comment: @breez - [Distinct](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,856287389e9cace3) uses a (hash?)Set internally.

Comment: ... kind of a "simplified"(?) `HashSet` as it seems. With the added bonus that `Distinct` keeps the original sorting. Well, not that much of a bonus here, since the very next step is an `OrderBy`, but still... ^_^;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private static IEnumerable<string> GetWords(string x)
    {
        return x.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
```

I should've thoroughly googled before. This code works. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Will that also include 1 and 2?

Comment: You'd think the *Chief Developer at Microsoft* would know this kind of thing... :)

Answer (score 0):

If the input looks like your CSV file, then consider:

```
var test = "Sunny,1\r\nSunny,2\r\nBobb,1";
var lines = test.Split('\r', '\n');
var vocabulary = lines.Select(z => z.Split(',')[0])
    .Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(word => word)
    .ToList();
```

*This will get you the text before the comma on each line, then remove duplicates.*